# Question about notation of $\bigwedge_{i=1}^{4}a_i$ and $\bigwedge_{i=1}^4 \bigvee_{j=1}^4 a_{ij}$

Tags: logic, notation, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

Hi maths people I have question about notations

$$\bigwedge_{i=1}^{4}a_i \text{ }\text{ and }\text{ } \bigwedge_{i=1}^4 \bigvee_{j=1}^4 a_{ij}$$

I think first one $\bigwedge_{i=1}^{4}a_i$ I understanded. You can write it like this:

$$\bigwedge_{i=1}^{4}a_i= a_1 \wedge a_2 \wedge a_3 \wedge a_4$$

But how is writed correct $\bigwedge_{i=1}^4 \bigvee_{j=1}^4 a_{ij}$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\bigwedge_{i=1}^4 \bigvee_{j=1}^4 a_{ij} =$$

$$ (a_{11} \lor a_{12} \lor a_{13} \lor a_{14}) \land (a_{21} \lor a_{22} \lor a_{23} \lor a_{24}) \land (a_{31} \lor a_{32} \lor a_{33} \lor a_{34}) \land (a_{41} \lor a_{42} \lor a_{43} \lor a_{44})$$

Comment: I think it is a matter of asking what does it mean by for all $x$ there exists $x$ $P(x)$, then as what I learnt about quantifier bounding, it reduces to there exists $x$ $P(x)$.

Comment: Yes Bram I choose own example that why it strange.. Very nice you see it can you pls say how this will look your expression?

Comment: Aha now understanded thank you very much Bram !!!!!

Comment: @Hamudii You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 3):

The third $i$ (in $a_{i}$) is bounded by the second $i$ ($\vee$), and the first $i$ ($\wedge$) bounds nothing, so $\wedge_{i}\vee_{i}a_{i}=\vee_{i}a_{i}$.

Comment: Sry your answer was all correct but I need change my question because I asked wrong..